# TypeORM PostgreSQL @ManyToOne save violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a basic nestjs app with 3 entities :

- `document: DocumentEntity`  has `pages: PageEntity[]` as `@OneToMany` relation
- `page: PageEntity` has `words: WordEntity[]`as `@OneToMany` relation + `@ManyToOne` document
- `word: WordEntity` has a `@ManyToOne` `page: PageEntity`

This is quite straightforward and the first part of those relations works as expected :
I can save new `pages` doing so :

```js
  async createPage(documentId: number, url: string) {
    const document = await this.documentRepository.findOne({ id: documentId });
    if (document) {
      const pageEntity = new PageEntity();
      pageEntity.imgUrl = url;
      pageEntity.document = document;
      await this.pageRepository.save(pageEntity);
    }
  }
```

but when I try to apply the same logic to the `words/page` relation, it fails. I m not sure why this behaves differently

```js
async postWord(pageId: number, word: { text: string }) {
    const page = await this.pageRepository.findOne({ id: pageId });
    if (page) {
      const wordEntity = new WordEntity();
      wordEntity.text = word.text;
      wordEntity.page = page;
      await this.wordRepository.save(wordEntity);
    }
  }
```

Error Message :

```
[ExceptionsHandler] null value in column "pageId" of relation "word_entity" violates not-null constraint +107723ms
QueryFailedError: null value in column "pageId" of relation "word_entity" violates not-null constraint
```

here are the entities declarations :

```
// document.entity.ts

@Entity()
class DocumentEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id?: number;

  @Column()
  public name: string;

  @Column()
  public locale: string;

  @Column()
  public pdfUrl: string;

  @Column()
  public folderPath: string;

  @OneToMany(() => PageEntity, (page) => page.document, {
    primary: true,
    eager: true,
    cascade: true,
  })
  public pages?: PageEntity[];
}

export default DocumentEntity;
```

```
// page.entity.ts

@Entity()
class PageEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id?: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public pageNumber?: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  public text?: string;

  @Column()
  public imgUrl: string;

  @OneToMany(() => WordEntity, (word) => word.page, {
    eager: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    primary: true,
  })
  words?: WordEntity[];

  @ManyToOne(() => DocumentEntity, {
    primary: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  public document: DocumentEntity;
}

export default PageEntity;
```

```
// word.entity.ts
@Entity()
class WordEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id?: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => PageEntity, {
    nullable: true,
    primary: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  public page!: PageEntity;

  @Column()
  public text: string;

  @Column({ type: 'decimal', nullable: true })
  public confidence?: number;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, working with ```synchronize: true``` can create problems/inconsistency if there are old entries present in tables and constraints change. Therefore, try to delete all the tables and/or rows that are affecred and then restart the application. TypeORM re-synchronize the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Entity()
class WordEntity {
  .....

  @ManyToOne(() => PageEntity, {
    nullable: true,
    primary: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'pageId',
    referencedColumnName: 'id',
  })
  page?: PageEntity;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  pageId?: number

  .....

}
```

```
async postWord(pageId: number, word: { text: string }) {
      const wordEntity = new WordEntity();
      wordEntity.text = word.text;
      // check if the pageId exists, maybe inside Dto with a decorator
      wordEntity.pageId = pageId;
      await this.wordRepository.save(wordEntity);
  
  }
```

Comment: Thx, adding a `pageId` key made it work. Had to remove `referencedColumnName: 'id'` though. Had a TypeOrmModule error `there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "page_entity"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `primary: true` from your `@ManyToOne` relation because a primary relation cannot be set as `NULL`